# One-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank test using scipy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I would like to perform a one-sided wilcoxon rank test to my paired data, as I'm interested if one sample is significantly greater than the other.

Scipy offers

```
scipy.stats.wilcoxon(x,y)
```

to perform a two-sided test with paired samples x and y. Since I can't assume a normal (symmetric) distribution, I can't derive the one-sided p-value from the two-sided p-value.

Does anybody now a python way to get the p-values for a one-sided test?

Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays, there is the option to set `alternative` to `'greater'` or `'less'`. Therefore, you do not have to compute it by yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

P value returned by `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` has nothing to do with the distribution of `x` or `y`, nor the difference between them. It is determined by the Wilcoxon test statistic (W as it in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test, or T as in `scipy`), which is assumed to follow a normal distribution. If you check the source (in ~python_directory\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py), you will find the last few lines of `def wilcoxon()`:

```
se = sqrt(se / 24)
z = (T - mn) / se
prob = 2. * distributions.norm.sf(abs(z))
return T, prob
```

and:

```
mn = count*(count + 1.) * 0.25
se = count*(count + 1.) * (2. * count + 1.)
```

Where `count` is the number of non-zero difference between `x` and `y`.

So, to get one-side p value, you just need `prob/2.` or `1-prob/2.`

Examples:
In `Python`:

```
>>> y1=[125,115,130,140,140,115,140,125,140,135]
>>> y2=[110,122,125,120,140,124,123,137,135,145]
>>> ss.wilcoxon(y1, y2)
(18.0, 0.5936305914425295)
```

In `R`:

```
> wilcox.test(y1, y2, paired=TRUE, exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  y1 and y2 
V = 27, p-value = 0.5936
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 

> wilcox.test(y1, y2, paired=TRUE, exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE, alt='greater')

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  y1 and y2 
V = 27, p-value = 0.2968
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

Comment: I haven't quite wrapped my head around it (need to re-study the wilcoxon test..) but the numbers speak for themselves. Thanks!

Comment: `up vote
3
down vote
accepted
P value returned by scipy.stats.wilcoxon has nothing to do with the distribution of x or y, nor the difference between them.` I'm confused.  I thought the test is saying the confidence if the 2 input vectors are from same distribution or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough observations (and other hypothesis) , I recall that the scipy Mann-Withney test is one-sided  : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I hadn't realised the slight difference between these tests. Now I just have to figure out which test is more suitable for my data.

Comment: mannwhitneyu is for independent samples, wilcoxon is for paired samples, so you cannot switch between them.

Comment: Actually you can: You can use a two-independent sample test on paired samples, but you cannot do it the other way around. Whether that is smart, is a totally different thing.